# How to detect programmatically if content under org-mode headline is encrypted or not before a save or commit?

Tags: org-mode, magit, git, version-control, gpg

`org-mode` allows users to encrypt the contents under a headline by adding the `crypt` tag with <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-q</kbd> <kbd>crypt</kbd> and then calling <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>org-encrypt-entry</kbd>.

Below is an example using this feature:

```
* Headline                  :crypt:
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----

jA0EBwMCtfdtKCPGXBdg0oQBDW4GlaBGCoAZNwNkQiP1+7oesTJkIHVbrHNV0StK
CDyLI8FADGlEY26dr7J1Ojo7HNy+aWGMBGTpBKDWZ0/ChB0JS39SKDL5DMEvYZuZ
c0Y6IuCnJ971nnM9rt+WHAs5i+LirGCPcTjrGLAasYEtrNwSPH2O9X+9PT1ze+r1
IOLfKZ0=
=9sC6
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

I would like to prevent users from saving the file and committing changes to a git repository if the content under a headline should be encrypted but is not.

The goal is to prevent unintentional leaks to local file system and stop unencrypted text from being added to the git repository.

> How to detect programmatically if content under `org-mode` headline is not encrypted before a save or commit?

I'm looking for an answer that could be called from the command-line for use in a on commit hook.

Thank you of your help!

---

> **emacs version:** 24.3 or greater
>   **org mode version:** 9.1.2 or greater
>   **git version:** 2.12.3 or greater
>   **gpg version:** 1.4.21 or greater

Answer (score 2):

From the commentary at the beginning of `org-crypt.el`:

```
;; 4. To automatically encrypt all necessary entries when saving a
;;    file, call `org-crypt-use-before-save-magic' after loading
;;    org-crypt.el.
```

So add to your `init.el` something like:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'org
  (require 'org-crypt)
  (add-hook 'before-save-hook #'org-crypt-use-before-save-magic))
```

Encrypting from a commit hook seems like the wrong time to do it. Perhaps your commit hook could more usefully test against the absence of `-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----` immediately following each `:crypt:` tag instead.